# How to connect to Oracle 12c DB with VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, oracle12c, vba

I have added a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.0 Library, and tried to execute the following code:

```
Sub Ora_Connection()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim query As String
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    strCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
        "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
        "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
        "(HOST=****)(PORT=****))" & _
        "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=****))); uid=****; pwd=****;"

    con.Open (strCon)

End Sub
```

I am getting these errors:

[image: Error1]
[image: Error2]

I have tried installing Oracle instant client ODBC drivers (I've tried 32bit and 64 bit versions) and I am having no luck.

I am not sure what the problem is.  I can connect to the database in Visual Studio 2012 with VB.Net, but I am unable to connect in excel 2010 using VBA.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!